# How to focus row that latest selected in datagridview of multiple selection allowed?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, focus

Is there any way to focus row which is latest selected for `DataGridView` which allow multiple selection?

I am using

```
dataGridView1.Rows[Index].Cells[Index].Selected = true;
```

It is selecting row but not focusing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[Index,Index];

Row selection is independent of focus.